# Unable to connect to SQL2005 using VBScript

Tags: sql-server-2005, vbscript

Using the connection string below I can connect to a SQL2000 DB but not a SQL2005. I have the code in an ASP file.

```
Dim connStr, cn, rs, sql
connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True" _
           & ";Initial Catalog=mydatabase"  _
           & ";User ID=dbuser" _
           & ";Password=dbpwd" _
           & ";Data Source=servername" 
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [Column1] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] order by NEWID()"
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open cn

set rs= server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorLocation=3
    rs.Open sql,cn,3,4

    if not rs.EOF then
       Response.Write("<b>Column1: " & rs("Column1") & "</b><br />")
    end if
set rs.ActiveConnection= nothing    
    rs.Close
    set rs= nothing
if ucase(TypeName(cn)) = "CONNECTION" then
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
end if
```

I have even tired with SQLOLEDB.1
Sql login is enabled on the sql server.

Error: The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.
Happens on rs.Open sql,cn,3,4

Comment: I have other .Net apps hitting that server without any problems.

Comment: Double check your permissions and tables on the sql2005 server; your connection code works fine for me with sql 2000, 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 3):

It happens to everybody sometime:

```
Dim connStr, cn, rs, sql
connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True" _
           & ";Initial Catalog=mydatabase"  _
           & ";User ID=dbuser" _
           & ";Password=dbpwd" _
           & ";Data Source=servername" 
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [Column1] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] order by NEWID()"
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open connStr
```

You are calling a variable **conn** as connection string but you have declared and filled **connStr**

Change "cn.Open conn" with "cn.Open connStr"

Comment: And always use "Option Explicit" to prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?  SQL Server 2005/8 install with remote connections disabled -- [check this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277).

I see, try setting your connString on your Connection object (you use conn instead of connStr).  Uee [option explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484(VS.85).aspx) to avoid these errors.

Comment: I updated the post with the error. The SQL 2005 is configured for remote connections. I have other .Net apps hitting that server without any problems.